# Using R and probability functions

Tags: probability-distributions, math-software

I am struggling a lot on this one. We are asked to use R a lot in one of my courses, with very little help or explanation so it's tough for those of us who are completely new to programs like R or Matlab.

I have probability function where $p_X(x) = \frac{c}{x}$, where $x = 1, 2, 3, ..., 1000$ and I need to solve for $c$, using R. I have absolutely zero idea on where to start, could someone point me in the right direction, or have any good well explained resources on how to use the R software?

Comment: What is $pX(x)$ ?

Comment: @Zoli, it's a probability function. X is the set, and x is the individual values within the set ( 1 to 1000)

Comment: Does that mean that choosing $x$ from $X$ is $\frac1{1000}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess $p_X(x)$ is a  [probability mass functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), and you have to compute $c$ from the condition
$$1=\sum_{x=1}^{1000} p_X(x)=\sum_{x=1}^{1000} \frac{c}{x}=c\sum_{x=1}^{1000} \frac{1}{x}$$
Using the relation of the [digamma function $\psi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers)
to harmonic numbers, the analytical value of the sum is
$$\sum_{x=1}^{1000} \frac{1}{x}=H_{1000}= \psi(1001)+\gamma \approx 7.485471$$
where $\gamma=0.5772156649\dots$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)
and therefore $c\approx 0.1335921$.
This is independent of R. In basic R there is a *digamma* function 
and you can use $\gamma = - \psi(1)$ to compute

```
> digamma(1001)-digamma(1)
[1] 7.485471
> 1/.Last.value
[1] 0.1335921
```

---

After reading a bit in the R documentation, I found, that you can also directly get the sum without special functions (showing a few more digits)

```
> sum(1/(1:1000))
[1] 7.485470860550345
```

and the constant c

```
> 1/sum(1/(1:1000))
[1] 0.1335921304924401
```